# Allow only specific format of numbers and letters to be accepted by textbox html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want my textbox in html to accept only specific format entered by user.

For example I want to enter roll number: F17-9006; F17-9007

First should be character, second and third should be numbers, a dash is automatically added, then four numbers after that and at the end semicolon is placed and then again the same for next entries.

Comment: you could use [jquery input mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for an input mask.
https://css-tricks.com/input-masking/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an [input pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp):

```
<input type="text" pattern="([A-Za-z]\d{2}-\d{4};)*">
```

Note that it won't automatically insert the dash, nor will it prevent the user from bypassing the browser's error checking.